Unable to remove Cross-Origin-opener-Policy in MV3 chrome extension
The below code updates a few network request rules.
Now if you look at rule id 2 we remove certain headers. I can see all of the other headers removal taking effect but not the Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy. is this some sort of limitation in MV3? This wasn't the case in MV2. Or am I doing some blunder in my code.
function updateDeclarativeNetRequestRules(options) {
    let rules = {
        removeRuleIds: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        addRules: [
            {
                id: 1,
                priority: 1,
                condition: {
                    requestDomains: ["ok.com"],
                    regexFilter: "(ok1)|(ok2)",
                    tabIds: globals.myTabs,
                    resourceTypes: ["script"],
                },
                action: {
                    type: "redirect",
                    redirect: {
                        url: "data:text/javascript,window"
                    }
                }   
            }, {
                id: 2,
                priority: 1,
                condition: {
                    tabIds: globals.myTabs,
                    resourceTypes: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "script", "xmlhttprequest"],
                },
                action: {
                    type: "modifyHeaders",
                    responseHeaders: [
                        { header: "x-frame-options", operation: "remove" },
                        { header: "content-security-policy", operation: "remove" },
                        { header: "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", operation: "remove" },
                        { header: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", operation: "set", value: "*" },
                        { header: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", operation: "set", value: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" },
                        { header: "permissions-policy", operation: "remove" },
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                id: 3,
                priority: 2,//priority higher than rule id:1 in order to prevent re-direction
                condition: {
                    requestDomains: ["ok.ok.com"],
                    regexFilter: "(ok3)|(s=ok4)",
                    tabIds: globals.myTabs,
                    resourceTypes: ["script"],
                },
                action: {
                    type: "allow"
                }   
            }
        ]
    };


    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules(rules, () => {
        chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getSessionRules(rules => console.log("updateDeclarativeNetRequestRules :: ", rules));
    });
}



Could be https://crbug.com/40196848 - devtools doesn't show the headers correctly. 2) These headers may be negotiated in the preflight request, try requestMethods: ['options']. 3) Report it in https://crbug.com.

